# Clicking in an input field does not focus

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem with forms. When I click in the input fields it does not focus.

Even if I just have an empty input field to test it does not work.

How do I solve this?

It worked before and suddenly it does not work. It works if I press tab to go through the form, but not if I click with the mouse.

Code example:

```
<form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit()">
<label for="name" class="form-label">Namn</label>
                        <input v-model="name" type="text" class="form-control w-75" id="name" required autofocus>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi You need to show some code about how you used the input.

Comment: and where is the css

Comment: I solved it. My z-index screwed it up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't specify any code for it, by default when you click on the input it doesn't seem to be selected even though it seems selected when you select it using the `tab` key.

To fix it you can add this css:

```
input:focus {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

This is a live example:

```css
#selectionInput:focus {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="selectionInput" placeholder="type here...">
<input  placeholder="type here...">
```

I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: No, it just get focus first, but when I click in the field it disappear.

Comment: Something must be overriding it. Try the live example it works. if it doesn't work then maybe it is something with your configuration or set up